# ASP.NET Ajax AutoComplete Not binding values?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, autocomplete

Iam using AJax: AUtoComplete in asp.net

Iam using WebMethod for the same page,

That webmethod is getting called and its returning values too.., But those values are not getting bind to the TextBox.

**Here is my ASPX code:**

```
 <asp:ScriptManagerProxy ID="AjaxMgrPrxy" runat="server" ></asp:ScriptManagerProxy> 

     <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtacService" AutoPostBack="true" ></asp:TextBox>

      <div id="divwidth"></div>

                 <ajax:AutoCompleteExtender ID="acService"  
                     TargetControlID="txtacService"  
                     runat="server" 
                     ServiceMethod="GetServiceNames" 
                     MinimumPrefixLength="1" 
                     EnableCaching="true" 
                     CompletionSetCount="1" 
                     CompletionInterval="200" 
                     CompletionListElementID="divwidth" 
                     ServicePath="PortOmission.aspx" 
                     FirstRowSelected="true"/>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string[] GetServiceNames(string prefixText)
{
   // Code Here
   return List.ToArray();
}
```

Did i miss come thing here??? I was looking into this code since few hrs.., i Could not get any useful result.,

Can any one please help me to find out this problem.,

Comment: Is any error in browser's console? Is `divwidth` element visible or not?

Answer (score 1):

If your service is in the same page as your textbox control is,
just use

ServiceMethod="GetServiceNames" 
 ServicePath=""